# Capture radio button status in wpFinished (non custom) in inno setup

Tags: click, capture, internet-radio

I am using Inno Setup V5 something the latest I could download.  I have a pretty solid install script developed.  I have set alwaysreboot to true but I need to display a messagebox to the user if he selects to reboot later.  How do I capture the radio buttons status.  I don't have time to completely replace this wpFinished page I need to get this done quickly so if that's the only way then I'll do it later and live with giving the warning even if he is rebooting. 
Thanks for the help.

Scott Beckstead

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to check state of radio buttons on wpFinished page when user clicks Finish:

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if(CurPageID = wpFinished) then
  begin
    // User clicked Finish on Finish page, check state of radio buttons
    if(WizardForm.NoRadio.Checked = True) then
      MsgBox('User selected Reboot Later.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

  Result := True; // Move to next page
end;
```

(not tested, I wrote this from my head)

If you want to react immediately to user action you need to use an OnClick event (TNotifyEvent):

Write your handler:

```
procedure ClickEvent(Sender : TObject);
begin
  // Do something here...
end;
```

Assign the Click Event (in InitializeWizard() or any other procedure):

```
WizardForm.YesRadio.OnClick := @ClickEvent; 
or
WizardForm.NoRadio.OnClick := @ClickEvent;
```